# How to save pygame scene as jpeg?

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl, pygame-surface

I need to do the following. I loaded an obj model using [OBJFileLoader](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/OBJFileLoader) and rendered it to a window. How can I save the rendered scene as a picture?
Is it possible to do this without even showing the window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can save a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object, object as the *Surface* associated with the screen with [`pygame.image.save()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.save):

> This will save your Surface as either a BMP, TGA, PNG, or JPEG image.

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))

# [...]

pygame.image.save(screen , "screenshot.jpg")
```

---

However, this doesn't work for `pygame.OPENGL` Surfaces. You must read the framebuffer with [`glReadPixels`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glReadPixels.html) before the display is updated (before `pygame.display.flip()` or `pygame.display.update()`). Use [`pygame.image.fromstring()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.fromstring) to create new *Surfaces* from the buffer. Finally, save the *Surface* to a file:

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h), pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.OPENGL)

# [...]

size = screen.get_size()
buffer = glReadPixels(0, 0, *size, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
pygame.display.flip()

screen_surf = pygame.image.fromstring(buffer, size, "RGBA")
pygame.image.save(screen_surf, "screenshot.jpg")
```

Comment: Is it possible to somehow hide the window so that it is not displayed?

Comment: @SomVolodya See [`pygame.display`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html): *"`pygame.HIDDEN` window is opened in hidden mode"* e.g.: `pygame.display.set_mode((w, h), pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.OPENGL | pygame.HIDDEN)` (since Pygame version 2.0)

Comment: my saved Image was upside down and flipped then, screen_surf = pygame.image.fromstring(buffer, size, "RGBA", True) works for me.